# Angularjs how to do proper error handling for $http call?

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, ionic-framework, error-handling, callback

My controller is getting empty or `undefined` data passed back from the service, which in turn is causing an error in the controller as not able to process `undefined` results.  I am rereading materials on error handling and am beginning to wonder if my error handling is incomplete.  Since my controller is getting the response, but the response is empty/undefined, then that means my service is still passing back bad response....but based on my service, I believe it should be handled with the `catch`.  How can I fix this so my service is processing the error and only passing back proper data to the controller?

Controller:

```
.controller('listCtrl', function($scope,listService) {

listService.getList(1)
.then(function(res) {
  if (res.list!= null) {   // <--- `Exception: Cannot read property 'list' of undefined`
     ...
     ...
  } else {
     ...
     ...
  }
}) ;
```

Service:

```
.factory("listService", function($http,$q) {
  // errMgmt 5100

  var headers={} ;
  var listMain = [] ;  // Current Lists
  var listPast = [] ;  // Past Lists


  function setVars() {
    baseUrl = "https://api.mydomain.com/v1/index.php" ;
    headers = {
      'Pragma':'no-cache', 
      'Expires': -1, 
      'Cache-Control':'no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate', 
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json',        
      'X-Requested-With':'com.mydomain',
      Authorization: 'Token ' +clientToken
    } ;
  }
      

  function getList(typeID) {
    if (typeID == 1) {
      listMain = [] ;
    } else if (typeID == 2) {
      listPast = [] ;
    }
    setVars() ;
    var dataObj = [{"type":typeID,"userID":userData.user_ID}] ;
    var req = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: baseUrl,
      timeout:httpTimeout,
      headers: headers,
      data: JSON.stringify(dataObj)
    }
     return $http(req)
    .then(function(response){
      if (typeID == 1) {
        listMain = response.data[0] ;  <-- Error happening, but being processed in success
        return listMain ;
      } else if (typeID == 2) {
        listPast = response.data[0] ;
        return listPast ;        
      }
    }).catch(function(err) {
      var msg = setError(err) ;
      errMgmt("services/getList",5100,msg) ;
    });
  }

  return {
    getList: function(typeID) {  // typeID : 1=current lsit, 2=past list
      return getList(typeID) ;
    }
 })
```

I have read various things, but one that catches my eye is that my service might need to be defined as:

```
return $http(req) {
.then(function(success) {   
   // success response
},function(error1) {
   // error response
}).catch(error2) {
   // catch all
}) ;
```

If this is the case, then what exactly is the difference between `function(error1)` vs the `.catch(error2)` - what specifically does each process?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling $http using success() and error()

```
.factory("listService", function($http,$q) {
  // errMgmt 5100

  var headers={} ;
  var listMain = [] ;  // Current Lists
  var listPast = [] ;  // Past Lists


  function setVars() {
    baseUrl = "https://api.mydomain.com/v1/index.php" ;
    headers = {
      'Pragma':'no-cache', 
      'Expires': -1, 
      'Cache-Control':'no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate', 
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json',        
      'X-Requested-With':'com.mydomain',
      Authorization: 'Token ' +clientToken
    } ;
  }
      

  function getList(typeID) 
  {
    if (typeID == 1) {
      listMain = [] ;
    } else if (typeID == 2) {
      listPast = [] ;
    }
    setVars() ;
    var dataObj = [{"type":typeID,"userID":userData.user_ID}] ;
    var req = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: baseUrl,
      timeout:httpTimeout,
      headers: headers,
      data: JSON.stringify(dataObj)
    }

    $http(req).success(function(data, status) 
    {
    if (status == 200) 
    {
      alert(data);
      if (typeID == 1) {
        listMain = data ;  
        return listMain ;
      } else if (typeID == 2) {
        listPast = data;
        return listPast ;        
      }       
      
    }
    }).error(function(data) 
    {
      alert(data);
    });   
  }

  return {
    getList: function(typeID) {  // typeID : 1=current lsit, 2=past list
      return getList(typeID) ;
    }
 })
```